# How to replace text of a particular line in string in c#?

Tags: c#

I need to replace a text with the new text of a particular line in a multiline string. Suppose I need to replace 6th line **6** with **Six**. I am doing in this way, But I don't think that this is the optimized way, Is there any better way to do this?

```
string str = "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9";
string[] output = str.Split('\n');
output[5] = output[5].Replace("6", "Six");
str = string.Join("\n", output);
```

Comment: I like your current approach.  You could try do a regex replacement, but the pattern would be fairly ugly.

Comment: Why not just replace 6 with the required value in the first instance? `var str = "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9".Replace("6", "Six");`

Comment: @Kami Because line 5 might also contain `6`.

Comment: @Kami Who says there is only one `6` in the file, or that `6` might occur before the sixth line?

Comment: @Kami but I want to replace only from that particular line, not from other places

Comment: @viveknuna you should add this to your question as your sample and question do not make this clear.

Comment: `string[] output = str.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, 5 + 2);` - we don't have to split into all, say, `12345678` lines; `7` will be enough

Comment: @DmitryBychenko didn't get your logic

Comment: @vivek nuna: suppose you have a *very long* text: `string str = "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11...\n12345678";`. If we want to replace `6` at `6`th line only, we don't have to split text into *all* `12345678` lines (what a huge array); we can obtain top `7` lines only.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko got your logic. But what if the string has 100000 lines and if last line's text needs to be replaced. Is there any way to split from the end also? as default split works from start.

Comment: @vivek nuna: well, in the *worst case* (replacemen in the very last line) you'll have the same performance.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko what about reversing the string and splitting with your logic in such cases (where n is big number)?

Comment: @vivek nuna: tecnically, it's possible, but I doubt if it's worth doing: we have to decide if line is big enough (and thus reversing) or not (business as usual). Suppose we a given `100 Mb` text and `line = 1000`. Should we reverse or not?